# Need help creating a christmas tree using python

Tags: python

I just started a python course in my university and need help solving an exercise. It is asking me to write a Christmas_tree.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried making one triangle/level?

Comment: I found some code on stack and tried to tweak it but still very lost on how to get the levels and shifts done

Comment: Describe the task in simple terms using human language. Then, implement this using Python. If you have an actual problem, please include a [mcve] in your question, along with actual and expected output. Also, don't put pictures of text into your questions, use the actual text (properly formatted) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two nested loops to handle the levels and the changes within each level, and use the `str.center` method to center each row.

```
>>> def christmas_tree(h, n, s):
...     max_width = 1 + 2 * h * n
...     width = 1
...     for _ in range(n):
...         for _ in range(h):
...             print(("*" * width).center(max_width))
...             width += 2
...         width -= 2 * s
...
>>> christmas_tree(5, 4, 2)
                    *
                   ***
                  *****
                 *******
                *********
                 *******
                *********
               ***********
              *************
             ***************
              *************
             ***************
            *****************
           *******************
          *********************
           *******************
          *********************
         ***********************
        *************************
       ***************************
```

Comment: Sam! Thank you so much for the help! This works incredibly